# Как сделать прокрутку до нужного элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Решил сделать прокрутку ленты с товарами как на crazybox.

Набросал пример - https://jsfiddle.net/cpjgL1ys.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.button button');


btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  const x = document.getElementById('active').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  document.querySelector('.goods').style.transform = `translateX(-${x}px)`;
  });
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как "центировать" элемент.

Т.е. мне нужно чтобы лента остановилась на id active. Я получаю его координаты через getBoundingClientRect. Так как их расчет идет сразу слева, а стрелка указывающая на выигрыш посередине, получается что и элемент с нужным id тоже останавливается слева, а не по середине как нужно. Мне удалось найти костыль в виде подсчета середины 170 * 4,5 элемента, но это будет работать только для конкретного разрешения экрана, а потом все сломается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать перемещение ленты до id active, и чтобы этот элемент был по середине стрелки.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

P.S. В codepen или jsfiddle getBoundingClientRect как я понял не работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  document.querySelector('#active').scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center',
    inline: 'center'
  });
});
```

Подробнее почитать про `scrollIntoView` можете [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). Это решение не будет работать в IE и Safari. Эти "но" устраивают?

Comment: Мне кажется это не совсем то, что нужно. Пролистывается все окно, хотелось бы что-то с translateX.